# Guava Cache: manual management by removal policy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, guava

**I have** something like this:

```
private final Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> peers = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();

public class Peer {       
    public void hanleRequest(String request) { ... }
    //....
}
```

`Cache` provides only two policies: `expiredAfterWrite` and `expireAfterAccess`. Either the first nor the second is suitable for me.

**I want** `BlockingDeque<Peer>` entity expires in 10 minutes after last invocation of `Peer#handleRequest()` method on one of `Peer` objects that belongs to that `BlockingDeque`. Means `Peer#handleRequest()` resets the expiration counter.

**I want** Any of other methods of `Peer` object doesn't reset counter.

**I want** peers.get(key) also doesn't reset counter.

**Example**

```
peers.getIfPresent(key); // doesn't reset counter
peers.getIfPresent(key).add(new Peer()); // doesn't reset counter
peers.getIfPresent(key).remove(peer); //doesn't reset counter
peers.getIfPresent(key).handleRequest(request); // RESET counter!
```

**Questions**

1. *Is that possible with help of Guava `Cache`, `ExpiringMap`, `MapMaker` or any other Guava map?*
2. If asnwer to the first question is NO. *Can I just customize one of the Guava elements to have no need to implement all from scratch?*
3. If answer to the second question is NO. *What is the better way to implement that by my own?* At the moment I suppose it'll be `ConcurrentHashMap` with daemon thread in addition. That thread will be iterate throught the whole map each 5-15 seconds and check if any entity is expired

***Updated:*** Is that a good solution? As I suppose, `handleRequest` is a operation which will be performed on each user request, so it performance stays on the first place. Approximate `BlockingDeque` objects in `peers` cache is near 10, approximate number of `Peer` object in one deque is 2.

```
private final Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> peers = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES) //CHANGE TO WRITE POLICY
    .build();

public class Peer {        
    public void hanleRequest(String request) { 
        BlockingDeque<Peer> deque = peers.getIfPresent(key);
        peers.invalidate(key);
        peers.put(key, deque);
        //...
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: Maybe pass the `Cache` and `Long` as arguments to the `Peer` constructor and call `cache.get(key)` in `handleRequest()`? This will reset the expiry counter.

Comment: @fge yes, but the question is how to not reset expiry counter on `cache.get` operation

Comment: Well, this method _will_ reset the counter. Note that I never told to assing the value to any variable.

Comment: Something to keep in mind about Guava caching cleanup behavior, from docs: `Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are rare.` More less it's not super granular by design.

Comment: @fge look at updated section of my question, please

Answer (score 5):

First a remark: The kind of question you ask smells like a XY problem, see:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
So maybe some background what you really want to achieve would be good.

Taking the question literally, I would do the following:

Use a second cache without expiration for the "don't reset counter" accesses. Add a removal listener to the peers cache, to remove the value from the second cache. Maybe just a HashMap is fine, too. The resource usage is actually controlled by the peers cache.

Comment: look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43295/cachelong-blockingdequepeer-combined-with-stripedreadwritelock-is-it-thr. There I posted the whole context. The question is quite different but code is the same.

Comment: seems I don't understand. Can you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

@cruftex's suggestion of using a second cache is fine.

Regarding your updated question, you don't need to invalidate before "updating" the value, just update it:

```
public class Peer {        
    public void handleRequest(String request) { 
        BlockingDeque<Peer> deque = peers.getIfPresent(key);
        if (deque != null) {
            peers.put(key, deque);
        }
        //...
    }
    //....
}
```